# Securing cryptographic key in memory

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, cryptography, key

I have a cryptographic key in my application. I need to secure the key in my memory. I know that using hardware memory can secure the key to a level, But I could find no resources or examples on the internet for this method. Is there any other way to achieve this or any example for using hardware memory available?

Comment: Do you mean `mlock`? Don't forget to overwrite the key before `delete` or when it goes out of scope. You might want to add a destructor that zeroes out the key.

Comment: Step 1: Figure out what you want to protect it from. This is called a threat model.

Comment: Probably better to look up some examples on the Internet rather than asking here.

Comment: I want to secure the key from any user reading the memory  or attach any form of a debugger to find the key

Comment: @user253751 I want to protect a key(master key).